# Why did the Rebels not try to Stop Rogue One from departing?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

In *Rogue One*, Jyn and her crew go to steal the Death Star plans from the Empire, doing so in the cargo shuttle they stole. They got away pretty easily after only some banter with control.

So, why did the Rebels not try and and stop them, and if they did, how so?

Comment: Do you mean why didn't the *Imperials* try to stop them?

Comment: i haven't seen the movie but i'm pretty sure it's "Rogue", not a film about make up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They took off very quickly and presumably jumped to lightspeed inadvisably close to the planet's gravity well, taking them outside the Rebel's sphere of influence in a very short period of time.

> “There is no ‘Rogue One,’” the person on the comm responded.
> “There is now,” K-2 said.
> **Bodhi gunned the engines** and took the shuttle into the air.
> “Rogue One pulling away,” he said.
> An instant later, they were gone.
>
> <sub><sup>[Rogue One: Official Novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Rogue_One:_A_Star_Wars_Story_(novelization))</sup></sub>

Comment: Thanks! So it was probably very similar to how they escaped Jedha then.